# Some types of nouns feel ungrammatical in "His every [noun]"?

Tags: noun-phrases, possessive-determiners

Abstract nouns, specifically nouns related to feelings, feel natural:

> Set A: His every {whim, desire, need, wish} should be satisfied by the council.

However, concrete nouns feel wrong.

> Set B: His every {photograph, watch, "piece of jewelry"} was placed in the safety deposit box.

Are the examples in "Set B" grammatically correct? If not, could you point me in the right direction to learn more about why they are ungrammatical?

Thank you.

**Edit**: How about a more clear example (without the passive voice)

> Set C: "His every song is good" (said another way, "I think all of his songs are good.")

Comment: They all sound find too me, although uncommon and with an archaic feel.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you. For my final question, does "Set C" also seem fine?

Comment: Your second example isn't passive—"good" isn't the past participle of a transitive verb, just an adjective, so you have an active sentence. If you swap it to "His every song is loved (by me)" or "His every song is thought (by me) to be good" then you're getting into passive construction.

Comment: @J.Doe It does. I was commenting on all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is grammatically correct though the  passive form sounds rather formal.

The possiblity of the Passive Voice here can be illustrated by an example from Reverso.context.net:

She ***was placed*** in the Dublin penitentiary for dealing in drugs by telephone.

There are some more examples but all of them are of the context.

In your case I would use the Active Voice  (for example, to place, to put) or  just the verb 'to be'.

But if the formal style is appropriate for the usage, you can use your sentence.

Comment: Ah, a great observation was made! ;) Could I trouble you to examine my edited answer?

Comment: Will you send it to me and the deadline, please!